# CocoaAsyncSocket processing hex values

Tags: ios, swift, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncSocket to process a fixed length header message. My node implementation is as follows

```
   var output = "\xA5\xA5" + jsonStr;    
   socket.write(output);
```

I intend to read the header first (\xA5\xA5) and then process the body of the message.

The problem that I have is that I've noticed that A5 takes 4 bytes to be represented in iOS. So when I read 2 bytes I receive c2a5.

CocoaAsync reading code

```
socket?.readDataToLength(2, withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?. I would like to keep a fixed length header on my server side.

Any help is much appreciated.